# Changing the frame of Image inside a UIImageview - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to change the frame of an image inside a `UIImageView` container.

Suppose I took a group photo and placed that image on a `UIImageView`, now I need to scroll the image so that I can  set my photo part (form the entire group photo image) on the centre of the `UIImageView`.

How to do this in iOS?

Comment: set your UIImageView content mode UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Comment: share your code that you have worked upon so far?